# PHP: Returning errors via HTTP POST and cathing them in CURL

Tags: php, http, curl

I'm having difficulty with passing back and dealing with errors in my application.  The application is built on PHP (version 5.3.29).

I have one page **TakePayment.php** which has a structure as follows:

```
try
{
    if( <<some condition>> )
    {
        <<log error>>
        header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
        exit;
    }

    <<take payment>>

    //if payment was ok, emit and empty json string
    Header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo "{}";
}
catch( Exception $e )
{
    <<log error>>
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
    exit;
}
```

I have another page **CancelAppointment.php** which has the following code:

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 5;
        $url = 'https://############/TakePayment.php';
        $formData = array('isCancellationPayment' => '1', 'booking_id' => $bookingId);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($formData));
        $data = curl_exec($ch);

        if(!curl_errno($ch))
        { 
            ?>
                 <p>Appointment has been cancelled </p>
            <?
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Fatal error taking payment, please contact PsychFinder support with the following information: ' . curl_error($ch); 
            exit;
        }
        curl_close($ch);
```

The issue I'm having is that the if(!curl_errno($ch)) block is not picking up the fact that the TakePayment.php page returned a 500 status code and is outputting the

Appointment has been cancelled

What am I doing wrong here, either in returning the 500 error or trapping it with CURL.

When I call the same page using client-side Ajax (in another part of the application) it's working as expected and the error is displayed if there is a payment issue, so it makes me think my CURL use is wrong?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/TakePayment.php",
    method: 'POST',
    data: {'booking_id': jsonData["bookingid"]},
    dataType: 'html',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) 
    {

    },
    error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
    {

        document.write("Error taking payment for session.  Please contact Support: " + errorThrown);
        throw new Error();

    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the issue you are having is that the TakePayment.php page returned a 500 status code, you just need a little more error checking when doing cURL requests. Technically curl_errno is for cURL errors, not errors that happened on the other end. This below snippet is something I use in a script that does many requests per day. Notice that even after I get a response, I still need to check for the HTTP status code, and that has nothing to do with if there were cURL errors or not.

```
// If there was a connection w/ response
if( $response = curl_exec( $ch ) )
{
    // Make sure the response indicates a success HTTP status code
    if( curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE ) != '200' )
    {
        // ... error at server ...
    }

    // The request was good
    else
    {
        // ... do something ...
    }
}

// If there was no successful connection or response
else
{
    $curl_info = curl_getinfo( $ch );

    // $curl_info may be useful in debugging
}
```